# Show @ symbol in different color in clojure mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, clojure

I want to show @ symbols (meaning dereference) in red in clojure-mode. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the examples in section [Customizing Search-Based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Keywords.html#Customizing-Keywords) of the elisp manual, I would propose this:

```el
(add-hook 
 'clojure-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (font-lock-add-keywords nil
           '(("\\(@\\)" 1 '(:foreground "red") prepend)))))
```

This uses an *anonymous face* with red foreground, any face could of course be used.